# React - How to separately assign click event to bunch of div's generated in loop

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, event-handling, click

I am trying to create my own Game of Life in React. Currently  have created a map with divs that will be separate cells in future when I finish my project. I also wanted to attach click event to each cell, but for some reason when I click single cell, the entire set of cells is affected. Can you please check why this happens? Also, can you please let me know if my approach is correct? Here is my index.js code:

```
class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this);
  }

  changeState() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
     isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
   }));
  }

  createMap = (cols, total) => {
    let table = []; let nL = ''; let idRow = 0; let idCol = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
      idCol++;
      if (i%cols === 0){
        nL = 'newLine';
        console.log(i%cols);
        idRow += 1;
        idCol = 0;
      }
      else {
        nL = '';
      }

      let toggledBackground = (this.state.isToggleOn ? 'test' : '');

      table.push(<div id={"row-"+idRow+"-"+idCol} className={nL+" square "+toggledBackground} onClick={this.changeState}></div>);
    }
    return table;
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.createMap(COLS, FIELDS)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can remove your css from the question because css is entirely irrelevant to this particular issue you're having. Also, remove any js code that is not relevant to the mapping and binding of the event.

Comment: what do you expect to happen when you click on a cell? when you pass `onClick={this.changeState}` it is the same function passed to every cell.

Comment: So let's say I have 1000 cells and when i click one of them I want to make change its background to red. But only the one that's clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `FIELDS` is the total number of cells (e.g for a 10x10 board, that would make FIELDS = 100). If that's the case, then you could bind the current index for each iteration to the said cell you are pushing in.

This way, you'll know which cell was clicked.

```
onClick={() => this.changeState(i)}
```

You'll also need to add a parameter to the actual function declaration, and save the state for that particular cell:

```
changeState(index) {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    let arr = prevState.cellStates.slice();
    arr[index] = !arr[index];
    return {cellStates: arr};
  });
}
```

Of course, this requires you to have an array, not a single boolean:

```
this.state = {cellStates: Array(FIELDS).fill(false)};
```

and finally for your styles:

```
let toggledBackground = (this.state.cellStates[i] ? 'test' : '');
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me check it out. For now it doesn't work but perhaps I have to check and make minor amendments.

Comment: @MateuszOsuch, yeah I haven't run your nor my code.

Comment: @MateuszOsuch, great! Please consider marking the answer as "accepted" if it fully answered your question.

Comment: if I have more question related to my project, shall I open a new thread or can I proceed in this one?

Comment: Feel free to open a new one, then ping me here with a link to the new question

Answer (score 1):

All of them are highlighted because they all share the same state, the easiest solution would be to make a separate component for the squares and pass down the needed data as props.

This will allow you to have separate state for every single cell.